# Set property of each object in list using forEach (Error: Local variables referred from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final)

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of matches. A match has a property called matchIndex. Now I want to set the property of each match in list like this

```
index = 0 // some predefined value

List<Match> matchList = createMatches(membersList, teamsPerGroup,totalGroups);
    matchList.forEach((match) -> {
    match.setMatchIndex(index++);
});
```

I want to set matchIndex of each match in the list by increasing order after local variable index.

Comment: `final int index = 0;`

Comment: I think a final value can't be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this because variables in lambda should be ***final or effectively final***.
you can follow this code:

```
IntStream.range(0, matchList .size())
            .mapToObj(index -> {
                Match match= list.get(index);
                match.setMatchIndex(index);
                return match;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or use `AtomicInteger`

```
AtomicInteger index= new AtomicInteger(1);
matchList.forEach(match-> match.setMatchIndex(index.getAndAdd(1)));
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As @Holger commented The correct solution is

```
IntStream.range(0, matchList.size()) 
         .forEach(index -> matchList.get(index) .setMatchIndex(index));
```

and if you want to use some predefined value this is right solution:

```
 IntStream.range(0, matchList.size()) 
          .forEach(index -> matchList.get(index) .setMatchIndex(index + offset));
```

Comment: What if I want to start the index from some predefined value?

Comment: go with second approach.

Comment: The correct solution is in-between: `IntStream.range(0, matchList.size()) .forEach(index -> matchList.get(index) .setMatchIndex(index));` And, by the way, why do you initialize the `AtomicInteger` with one, contradicting every other example?

Comment: @Holger, Thanks for your feedback. OP commented _What if I want to start the index from some predefined value?_ so I though second way was for it.

Comment: I see. So you should make it clear right in the answer, that this is addressing an additional point (as readers should not be required to read the comments to understand an answer). Of course, that would work with the canonical solution too: `IntStream.range(0, matchList.size()) .forEach(index -> matchList.get(index) .setMatchIndex(index + offset));`

Comment: @Holger, I can only say this proverb .Truth has no answer!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a lazy way to do it but it's not the Java 8 way. Still, I am posting this answer:)

```
int index = 0; // starting index

for (Match match: matchList) {
    match.setMatchIndex(matchIndex++);
}
```

Hope it helps.